# Closure: Example of a rock song that cadences iiø7-V-i

Tags: discussion

[Example of a minor-key rock song that ends with a ii∅7-V-i cadence](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/10215/7708)

This question was just closed as *too broad.*  I don't get why.  I am just limiting to an example of a rock song that cadences ii<sup>ø</sup>7-V-i.

Why was it closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too broad, because rock is broad.

On-topic recommendation questions need to have more constrains than just a genre that almost means nothing by itself.

You need to be more specific about what you are looking for, and what would deserve the acceptance. Consider that several users understand what you are talking about, and write answers, which one would be the accepted one?